# Trying to set the node version as 19.2.0

Tags: node.js, linux, terminal, nodes, nvm

How can I use the node version as 19.2.0 using nvm.
Evertime i have to start nvm and set the node version as v 19.2.0 but when i close the terminal it sets back to v10.19.
I'm using Linux mint v20+

I want to set the node version as v19.2

Comment: I tried to set nvm alias default v19.2  & &  nvm use default. it didn't worked

Comment: does executing `set | grep -i node` return anything? OR do you know that there is a specific env variable used to stored the `node` version? If so, use `set | grep -i myNODE_VER_THINKGY` and see what version is automatically kept in your environment. Then you have to trace true all the "dotfiles" (`.profile, .bash_rc`, etc, etc) and see where that is set and change it there. OR you could create a startup wrapper that include `export myNODE_VER_THINGY=v19.2` and see if that works. Good luck.